# What's the use case for gRPC where it could definitely overcome REST

Tags: rest, grpc

I made up simple benchmarking for the simpliest case: sending string Hello world over gRPC and rest in ruby:

```
# REST example
require 'sinatra'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :logging, false

get '/' do
  'Hello, world!'
end
```

gRPC example is based on official [examples](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/ruby.html)

```
// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}

class GreeterServer < Helloworld::Greeter::Service

  def say_hello(hello_req, _unused_call)
    Helloworld::HelloReply.new(message: "Hello #{hello_req.name}")
  end
end
```

deployed this code to remote server and run 1000 requests benchmark (`ab` for rest and looping client requests for gRPC) and get comparable results 51 sec vs 53 (REST vs gRPS)

so, I made up conclusion that in that case (with small amount of data in response) there is no benefits to gRPC. So, when would they appear? When data size would be magnitude of kilobytes or even megabytes? Or there are essentially different use cases for gRPC like streaming and duplexing data between server and client?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2018/07/rest-vs-grpc/) indicates that gRPC performs better while being slightly harder to use.

I'm think the improved performance comes from using protocol buffers for data transmission; I believe that means data is transmitted in binary format which would mean improved performance when you have more data, particularly non-string data.